# Cannot remove appended hidden input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically add hidden input to my form. If you're messaging say four people at once (whose names are in `callsign_array`) it will add four hidden inputs. The form is then submitted using ajax. I then want to remove all the appended hidden inputs, but `$('.remove').remove();` isn't working (if you send a message to Andy, then try to send a different message to Barry, it actually sends the message to Andy and Barry. Sending a third message to Chas would result in a message to Andy, Barry and Chas). I know there are thousands of similar "jquery remove() doesn't work" questions on SO, I've looked at them and I think this should work, but I'm baffled, I just can't see what's wrong.

```
var callsign_array = $('#callsigns-div').data('callsigns');
var form = $("#message_form");
for(var i=0; i<callsign_array.length; i++) {
  form.append('<input type="hidden" class="remove" name="callsigns[]" value="' + callsign_array[i] + '" />');
}
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:  $(this).attr('action'),
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'script'
});
// remove all appended inputs
$('.remove').remove();
// reset the callsigns array
$('#callsigns-div').attr('data-callsigns', '[]');
```

The page includes this div to hold the callsigns array:

```
<div id="callsigns-div" data-callsigns='[]'></div>
```

Comment: your code seems fine. can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: also your ajax has no callback

Comment: there is not enough code in your question to understand why the behaviour you describe occurs. How are `this` and `form` variables related?

Comment: this isnt enough code to decide what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<crystalball on>`

You are not removing entries from your `callsign_array` container. That is why messages for different users accumulate.

`</crystalball off>`

Add logging:

```
console.log("Before remove: ", $('.remove').length);
$('.remove').remove();
console.log("After remove: ", $('.remove').length);
```

to convince yourself that `$().remove` works.

*Update*

Do not mix `$().data` and `$().attr` calls when reading/writing dataset properties of DOM elements. These dataset items are cached as separate memory objects by jQuery.

Add logging:

```
$('#callsigns-div').attr('data-callsigns', '[]');
console.log("Hope array is empty: ", $('#callsigns-div').data('callsigns'));
```

to convince yourself that your `$().attr` call does nothing to the result of the subsequent `$().data` call.

Comment: Your console.log suggestion revealed that .remove is working....
I am removing entries from `callsign_array`, the problem is elsewhere.
Sorry to have wasted everyone's time. I'm going to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

@robert-wade is correct. I don't have reps to comment but you might consider holding all of your users in an array or object and then passing that array/object in the form.  It's a little cleaner than adding/removing elements.  Of course you would have to parse it on the server-side.

Answer (score -1):

> try this

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST', 
url: $(this).attr('action'), 
data: $(this).serialize(), 
dataType: 'script' ,
success: function (){
$('.remove').remove(); // reset the callsigns array 
$('#callsigns-div').attr('data-callsigns', '[]');
}
}); // remove all appended inputs
```

Comment: you should specify the error in the code first,  rather than copy pasting here .